# How to update a contend without refresh, BUT except one element inside this content?

Tags: php, ajax, refresh

I have some DIV in my page, they are like `<div class="playing-track">`. For a lot of them, the parent div has children, and I can update anyone of them without refresh, its working, BUT...

I want to update the DIV "playing-track", but I do not want to update a span element inside it. here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     //REFRESHING DIV AUTOMATICALLY TO CHANGE ARTIST DETAILS:
    setInterval("my_function();",5000); 
    function my_function(){
      $('.playing_track').load(location.href + ' .playing_track');
    }
    
</script>
<pre><?php
    <div class="playing-track">
       <div class="playing_1">
           <div class="playing_2">
           </div>
           <div class="playing_3">
           </div>
           <span class="message_inside">
          </span>
       </div>
    </div>
?> </pre>
```

I want to update .playing-track without refresh.
I can get it, BUT.
I want to do this, without refreshing span element `.message_inside`.

Is it possible?

I have a form submitted on this page by ajax to a php page which sends it to database.

I have a form that I send information to database trough ajax.
But I noticed that the ajax code is entering in conflict with the loading without refresh div JavaScript code, so loading div without refresh JavaScript code when getting the div where the form is, make the submitevent get slow, very slow.

This is the reason of my question guys, can I solve it anyway?
My Javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript" > 
//<script type="text/javascript" > // Liking songs user_ip
  $(function () {
    $(".button_like_song").click(function (event) {
      var songID = $("#songID").val();
      var artist_liked = $("#artist_liked").val();
      var title_liked = $("#title_liked").val();
      var liked = $("#liked").val();
      var song_date_rated = $("#song_date_rated").val();
      var song_date_played = $("#song_date_played").val();
      var song_duration = $("#song_duration").val();
      var current_user_ip = $("#current_user_ip").val();
      var dataString = 'songID=' + songID + '&artist_liked=' + artist_liked + '&title_liked=' + title_liked + '&liked=' + liked + '&song_date_rated=' + song_date_rated + '&song_date_played=' + song_date_played + '&song_duration=' + song_duration + '&current_user_ip=' + current_user_ip;
      console.log(dataString);
      if (songID == '' || artist_liked == '' || title_liked == '' || liked == '' || song_date_rated == '' || song_date_played == '' || song_duration == '' || current_user_ip == '')
      {
        $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
        $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
      } else
      {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "get_likes.php",
          data: dataString,
          success: function (data) {
            $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
            $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
            $("#feedback_message").html(data);
          }
        });
      }
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  });
//</script>
//<script type="text/javascript" > // Disliking songs
  $(function () {
    $(".button_dislike_song").click(function (event) {
      var songID_disliked = $("#songID_disliked").val();
      var artist_disliked = $("#artist_disliked").val();
      var title_disliked = $("#title_disliked").val();
      var disliked = $("#disliked").val();
      var song_date_disliked = $("#song_date_disliked").val();
      var song_date_played_disliked = $("#song_date_played_disliked").val();
      var song_duration_disliked = $("#song_duration_disliked").val();
      var current_user_ip_disliked = $("#current_user_ip_disliked").val();
      var dataString = 'songID_disliked=' + songID_disliked + '&artist_disliked=' + artist_disliked + '&title_disliked=' + title_disliked + '&disliked=' + disliked + '&song_date_disliked=' + song_date_disliked + '&song_date_played_disliked=' + song_date_played_disliked + '&song_duration_disliked=' + song_duration_disliked + '&current_user_ip_disliked=' + current_user_ip_disliked;
      console.log(dataString);
      if (songID_disliked == '' || artist_disliked == '' || title_disliked == '' || disliked == '' || song_date_disliked == '' || song_date_played_disliked == '' || song_duration_disliked == '' || current_user_ip_disliked == '')
      {
        $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
        $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
      } else
      {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "get_dislikes.php",
          data: dataString,
          success: function (data) {
            $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
            $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
            $("#feedback_message").html(data);
          }
        });
      }
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  });
//</script>
//REFRESHING DIV AUTOMATICALLY TO CHANGE ARTIST DETAILS:
    setInterval("my_function();",5000); 
    function my_function(){
      $('.playing_track').load(location.href + ' .playing_track');
    }
  

</script>
```

PHP CODE (The most important part [Below this code, there is more code, and table and div where recent songs and coming soon songs are]). Below coming soon and recently played songs are supposed to be reloaded without refreshing page too, but the form is between both important code to be reloaded (artist Bio, artist - Title [Now playing info], coming up next songs/artists, and recently played songs)

```
<?php   

     $ch = curl_init();
    
    $artist = strtolower("$artista_da_biografia");
    $fields = array('method' => 'artist.getInfo',
                'artist' => $artist,
                'api_key' => $lastfm_apikey,
                'lang' => 'pt');
    
    $fields_string = "";
            
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    rtrim($fields_string,'&');
    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    
    $response = curl_exec($ch)or die( curl_error($ch) );
    curl_close($ch);  
    $s = simplexml_load_string($response);
    //================================PARTIAL END OF SHOWING ARTIST IMAGE WITH LAST FM API================================//
    //=========NOW PLAYING IMAGE AND INFO========================

echo "<div class=\"playing_track\">";
echo    "<div id=\"first_live_stat\">";
echo        "<div id =\"logo_live_stat\"><div id =\"logo_live_stat_image\"></div></div>"; 
echo        "<p class=\"header_live\"> BIOGRAPHY </p>\n";
?>           <div id="artist_bio"><p><?php echo nl2br(strip_tags($s->artist->bio->content)); ?></p></div>
<?php
echo    "</div>";

?>      <div class="img_now_playing_artist">
            <h1 style="text-transform:uppercase;"><?php //print $artist; ?></h1>
            <img src="<?php print $s->artist->image[3]; ?>" alt="<?php print $artist; ?>" />
        </div>
<?php 
    echo "<div id=\"now_playing_text_and_buttons\">";
    echo "<table class=\"coming_up_next\">" . "\n";
        echo " <tr>" . "\n";
        echo "   <td class=\"header_live\">NOW PLAYING</td>\n";
        echo " </tr>" . "\n";
        echo "<tr><td><div id=\"now_playing_text\"><strong>"  . htmlspecialchars($row['artist'], ENT_QUOTES) . " </strong><br/> " . htmlspecialchars($row['title'], ENT_QUOTES) . "</div></td></tr>"; 
        echo "<tr><td><div id=\"like_buttons\">";
        echo "<form id=\"thumb_up\" name=\"like\" action=\"$receivelikespage\" method=\"post\">";
            echo " <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"$songid\" id=\"songID\" name=\"songID\"/>\n";
            echo " <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"$artist_now_playing\" id=\"artist_liked\" name=\"artist_liked\"/>\n";
            echo " <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"$title_now_playing\" id=\"title_liked\" name=\"title_liked\"/>\n";
            echo " <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"1\" id=\"liked\"  name=\"liked\"/>\n";
            echo " <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"$song_date_rated\" id=\"song_date_rated\" name=\"song_date_rated \"/>\n";
            echo " <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"$song_date_played\" id=\"song_date_played\" name=\"song_date_played\"/>\n";
            echo " <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"$song_duration\" id=\"song_duration\" name=\"song_duration\"/>\n";
            echo " <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"$current_user_ip\" id=\"current_user_ip\" name=\"current_user_ip\"/>\n";
            echo " <button type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\" class=\"button_like_song\" id=\"button_like_song\" name=\"submit\"><div id=\"up\"></div></button>\n";
            echo '<br />';
        echo "</form>";
        echo "<form id=\"thumb_down\" name=\"dislike\" action=\"$receivedislikespage\" method=\"post\">";
            echo " <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"$songid\" id=\"songID_disliked\"  name=\"songID\"/>\n";
            echo " <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"$artist_now_playing\" id=\"artist_disliked\" name=\"artist_disliked\"/>\n";
            echo " <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"$title_now_playing\" id=\"title_disliked\" name=\"title_disliked\"/>\n";
            echo " <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"-1\" id=\"disliked\"  name=\"disliked\"/>\n";
            echo " <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"$song_date_rated\" id=\"song_date_disliked\" name=\"song_date_rated\"/>\n";
            echo " <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"$song_date_played\" id=\"song_date_played_disliked\" name=\"song_date_played\"/>\n";
            echo " <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"$song_duration\" id=\"song_duration_disliked\" name=\"song_duration\"/>\n";
            echo " <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"$current_user_ip\" id=\"current_user_ip_disliked\" name=\"current_user_ip\"/>\n";
            echo " <button type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\" class=\"button_dislike_song\" id=\"button_dislike_song\" name=\"submit\"><div id=\"down\"></div></button>\n";
            echo "<br />";
        echo "</form>";
            echo "<span id=\"feedback_message\"></span></div></td></tr>";
        

?>
```

The form's purpose is to submit listener rating (like / dislike a song).

So I can't take the span message_feedback to another part of the code, because it'll get my CSS layout crazy at all.

Comment: You are only showing your html code, where is your javascript code for updating your divs.

Comment: You can take span out of div if you don't want it to be updated.

Comment: Nancy Mooree,the problemis if i take span out of that div,my allcode gets crazy on screen,it is supposed tobe there in that position, unless,i positioning it by css, but I really dont wthink its gonna be a good idea,fixing that span,probably would be better try to update only the text i want, im gonn show my javascript,but this is only a clear explanation of coed,my code ismuch more complicated.

Comment: even if I take it out, probglems happen, contend in form is being post when i refresh the page by pressing f5 for example. :( please someone help me!